# How to enable NFS4 protocol

Tags: debian, nfs, protocols

I have found nothing that could help me with enabling NSF4 protocol

```
rpcinfo -u localhost nfs
program 100003 version 2 ready and waiting
program 100003 version 3 ready and waiting
```

How can I add version 4? I am on a Debian flavor.

(I have more PC's with Debian/Ubuntu Linux and NFS4 installed already. But NFS4 protocol was available out of the box. I checked `/etc/hosts.allow/deny`, `/etc/defaults/nfs-kernel-server` + `nfs-common` are setup correctly - `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server` is identical with the one on other working PC - what can I do?)

Comment: OK, I assume now it's an issue with the kernel module nfsd.ko.

Answer (score 1):

You need a kernel with nfs4 support.

To check if your kernel has it:

```
$ grep NFS /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_NFS_FS=m
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1=y
CONFIG_NFSD=m
CONFIG_NFSD_V2_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=m
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
```

and

```
# rpcinfo -u localhost nfs
program 100003 version 2 ready and waiting
program 100003 version 3 ready and waiting
program 100003 version 4 ready and waiting
```